# What object am I? -- white, dry, not green

Tags: riddle

I am white. I am dry.

Not a dusty green or a powdery black.

I compete against smart.

What am I?

Answer (score 6):

> You are a Whiteboard.

I am white. I am dry.

> Refers to the color of the board.

Not a dusty green or a powdery black.

> Unlike the traditional colors of the blackboard

I compete against smart.

> Students write on whiteboard and prove their intelligence.

Comment: I think you're missng one small piece: (rot-13) N "Fzneg" obneq vf n oenaq bs ryrpgebavp obneq.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's

> **Chalk**

---

I am white. I am dry.

> This accurately describes generic chalkboard chalk.

Not a dusty green or powdery black.

> Those colors better describe a chalkboard. Chalk in those colors may not be visible on some chalkboards.

I compete against smart.

> An alternative to chalk is a stylus. A stylus may be used on a [SMART Board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Technologies), an alternative to a chalkboard for use in classrooms.

Comment: rot13(Lbh ner qrsvavgryl ba gur evtug genpx jvgu gur terra naq oynpx punyxobneq nf jryy nf gur fzneg-obneq! V guvax lbhe rkcynangvba znxrf frafr gbb. Ubjrire, V jnf guvaxvat bs fbzrguvat pybfre gb n punyxobneq naq n fzneg-obneq.)

Answer (score 2):

I am...

> ...the "Post your Answer" box on the Puzzling.SE website

I am white. I am dry.

> It's white.  And it's "dry" in the sense it's barren or empty (or at least it was until I wrote this answer).

Not a dusty green or a powdery black.

> Here "dusty green" refers to the background color, and "powdery black" refers to the bar at the top (I think it's called the [Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/351283)).

I compete against smart.

> That's what it is used for.

Answer (score 0):

> Iphone. An object associated with apple but not mildew.

Comment: rot13(abg dhvgr! V'z abg fher ubj vg jbhyq 'pbzcrgr ntnvafg fzneg'.)

Comment: rot( ntnvafg abg nccyr fznegcubar) ,but then I don`t know:)

Comment: @balazs.com  I think you should explain your answer more in general. I have seen multiple answers where you simply write it down without proper justification

Comment: But i can`t explain it further, I thought it was a white and dry apple with no mold on it.  But by the way, I think the "computer" tag should have been added, I particularly have nothing to do with computers, nor with mathematics, believe it or not.)It is not trivial... (That`s why, for example, I add "knowledge" tag to my own puzzles if serious non-trivial knowledge is required.) Just for the future.

Comment: An explanation means a line-by-line justification of why you think your answer is correct; otherwise it is more of a guess, or only partial match with the clues in the question. That's all I meant :)

Comment: Ok, I will do this. Is it necessary in general or if OP requests it? (Eg. I don`t require line by line explanations, if one knows the answer I am sure he knows everything). But if it is a general rule for every single answer, let it be like that

Comment: It is not a rule as such, but it is easier for a third person reading your answer to understand why it may be the correct answer